# WPF vertical Slider Custom Template - mouse drag horizontal

Tags: .net, wpf

I just created a custom template to customize the slider style.
However, the vertical orientation rotates correctly but to drag the thumb vertically I need to move the mouse horizontally.... this seems to me something that has to be overridden, but how?

L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible you are rotating the entire thumb. If yes, that's the problem. You should rotate just the canvas that contains the thumb element (image, shape or path)